# Backbone event binding using Descendants selector

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I have an event delegation object declared like so:

```
events:{
    'click .outer .showMore':'showMore',
    'click .showLess':'showLess'
}
```

The first one does not fire. I can type

```
$('.outer .showMore').on('click',function(){alert('test')})
```

into the console and it will bind that event. The .showMore element is in my template, it is not being added dynamically. It works if I take out the .outer, however, I need that to prevent bleed over to other views.

What am I missing? Even the [Backbone docs for delegateEvents](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents) shows a descendant selector.

This is a Marionette project, but I believe these issues to be Backbone related.

Comment: Is there a better way to bind events that apply only to my current view?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out when binding events via the events hash, Backbone is smart enough to only bind elements on the current view. This means I don't need to use the .outer selector at all.

The reason it didn't work, I would imagine, is Backbone is probably prepending my view class to the selector before passing it to jQuery for binding. so It was likely trying to bind '.outer .outer .showMore'